# In Visual Studio 2022 is there some way to automatically accept a large block of suggestions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I'm getting a bunch of messages saying

> Message IDE0090
> 'new' expression can be simplified

I would like to have the suggested correction made to all of them without having to manually do them one by one.

I'll backup first, so I'm not worried about it messing up my project.

Comment: Currently no you have to manually accept (and review) each one, not even ReSharper suggestions support this: https://superuser.com/questions/1492462/visual-studio-lightbulb-keyboard-shortcut  You can suppress the warnings in one go, but not accept-all suggestions as that could lead to potentially thousands of issues. Best bet is the Refactor or Rename functionality in VS2022 or writing a RegEx to work across project files in bulk implementing the suggestions.

Comment: some of the can be run in bulk using Analyze->Code Cleanup

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does this link not exist in Visual Studio 2022?

[image: fix all occurrence]

---

**Update** Now that I am using 2022 community, this option still exists:

[image: fix all occurrence in 2022]

Comment: You can install VS 2022 and check it yourself before answering)

Comment: I can confirm this exists in both 2017 and 2019. It seems a little expensive to download a new version.

Comment: Yep, the "Fix all occurrences in: ... Project" link exists in VS2022, and facilitates the bulk correction of a CA warning. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Is this also available on Visual Studio 2022 Professional? That option does not appear when I try to apply the fix.

Comment: @paddingtonMike I can only answer you this is available on community version.