# Replacing CLR Types with c# alias types in an enitre Codebase

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring

I'm looking for a way to easily replace all CLR-Type references in a codebase with a few thousand files with their respective alias types, specifically:

- "Int64"  => "long"
- "Int32"  => "int"
- "Int16"  => "short"
- "UInt64"  => "ulong"
- "UInt32"  => "uint"
- "UInt16"  => "ushort"
- "Double"  => "double"
- "Single"  => "float"
- "Decimal"  => "decimal"
- "Byte"  => "byte"
- "SByte"  => "sbyte"
- "Object"  => "object"
- "String"  => "string"
- "Char"  => "char"
- "Boolean"  => "bool"

I've found this tool [AliasBeGone](https://github.com/perbrage/aliasbegone) that does it the other way around and is for older visual studio versions and only for a single file at a time.
Is there a tool out there that can do what I'm trying to achieve or is it best if I keep trying to make a solution of my own using either a console application or a bash script?

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Resharper/Rider can do this.

Comment: Can you open the codebase in Visual Studio?

Comment: @shingo yes, is there an extension for that?

Comment: Related: [string vs. String is not a style debate](https://blog.paranoidcoding.org/2019/04/08/string-vs-String-is-not-about-style.html).

Comment: BTW, main problem here would be to avoid wrong replacements. Doing things automatically might cause replaces you really shouldn't have done (written from the perspective of a painful experience). Be careful.

Comment: No need, hover the mouse cursor over a CLR-type, you will see a [similar popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71201162/in-visual-studio-2022-is-there-some-way-to-automatically-accept-a-large-block-of/71202095#71202095).

Comment: @shingo When I move the cursor over a CLR type nothing pops up :( It pops up on other things but not on CLR-Types. Does this have something to do with preference settings? I can't find any settings like that in Visual Studio 2022. It would be a great solution though

Comment: @shingo I found the issue and can now use that popup after I edited the .editorconfig file with the following lines 
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_locals_parameters_members = true:silent
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_member_access = true:silent
This helped me greatly thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness if anyone else has the same issue I'll post this as an answer here.

As [shingo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6196568/shingo) pointed out this can be achieved with Visual Studio using [a similar popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71201162/in-visual-studio-2022-is-there-some-way-to-automatically-accept-a-large-block-of/71202095#71202095) from a previous answer of theirs.

This popup should appear when you hover over a CLR type and you can replace all occurrences in the solution. If this popup doesn't appear you should check your solutions `.editorconfig` file.

Make sure the following lines are included there:

- `dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_locals_parameters_members = true:suggestion`
- `dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_member_access = true:suggestion`

Then it should work. If anyone has a better solution please feel free to post it here too.